# Why my fabric plugin blank after distribute new build?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I got below result after distributing my new build from xcode,

[image]

I don't get this blank before updating my fabric io. There used to be alert label if I either succeed uploading my new build or failed uploading my new build. I cant really know if my new build already distributed or not with this blank.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, there are issues with fabric 2. So first try to restart fabric and if then also it is same then upgrade the version to 2.0.1.

Comment: @MukeshThawani I have version 2.0.1 fabric on my mac, is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: right now your app is not responding so you can do one thing  remove this folders: ~ / Library / Caches / com.crashlytics.data ~ / Library / Caches / com.crashlytics.mac. This may solve the problem.

Comment: @MukeshThawani I still got the same problem after removing both folder

Comment: @MukeshThawani I also tried that and it did not work :(

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra I also have this issue, did you manage to solve it? It's possibly related to certificates/prov profiles, but I can't test it as the developer portal is down for maintenance at the moment.

Comment: @DaveTheKiwi I still cant fix this issue but I email the suport and got this:
Below comment

Comment: @DaveTheKiwi try this then let me know if you face any problems.

Comment: @MukeshThawani I've tried that, sitll got the same problem

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra when you restart the app then what is coming? If it is normal then look at your last distribution and tell me what it is showing?

Comment: @MukeshThawani it distributed but my tester not receiving my last distribution, my fabric app just frozen and blank after distributing

Comment: Yeah, that will happen that's why you are seeing your app like this. What you should try is restart the app and then see what it is showing and then I will understand more about it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

Close fabric, increment your build number in Xcode, clean the project, open fabric, then build and archive your project. When it is finished and you distribute it then it will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue few days ago and here how I solved it:

1. ** Get an uninstaller for mac (here is a free one http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) and use that to remove fabric completely.
2. Empty Trash
3. Restart your Mac
4. Remove fabric from xcode project by removing build script and frameworks. You may need to comment some code depending on your setup.
5. Clean/Build, fix errors if any.
6. Download latest fabric and install
7. Follow their instruction to setup the project again, (e.g. adding build script)

** Make sure the uninstaller you choose deletes every and all related files to fabric. It usually shows you list of files it's about to delete.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the regular "cleaning" of the build, try to build when Fabric is open. It acts weirdly when if it's not open already on build. Fabric 2.x is *extremely* problematic. I hate the day I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, initially i was able to upload the builds even with fabric version 2.0 and above. The problem started when there was a build being uploaded and it was taking some time and i closed the fabric app.

The solution for me was signing with a different user of the team who had access for the the projects and upload the build.

As mentioned in the above answers, deleting fabric didn't work (probably because i didn't delete all my files, incrementing the version number for the project and cleaning didn't work either).